# What is a good algorithm for automatic type conversion for basic types in a compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction

I'm developing a simple compiler, and want to implement automatic type conversion in a proper way. The types I have are for example byte, int, uint16_t, uint64_t, int16_t, float, double, etc. The compiler should check types, and determine if a value of a certain type can be used as another type.

For example, an int16_t value can be used without problem as a int32_t value, because no precision is lost. Using a int32_t value where a int16_t is expected should raise a warning or an error.

The code I have so far is the following:

```
def do_coerce(self, expr, typ):
    """ Try to convert expression into the given type.

    expr: the expression value with a certain type
    typ: the type that it must be
    Raises an error is the conversion cannot be done.
    """
    if self.context.equal_types(expr.typ, typ):
        # no cast required
        pass
    elif isinstance(expr.typ, ast.PointerType) and \
            isinstance(typ, ast.PointerType):
        # Pointers are pointers, no matter the pointed data.
        expr = ast.TypeCast(typ, expr, expr.loc)
    elif self.context.equal_types('int', expr.typ) and \
            isinstance(typ, ast.PointerType):
        expr = ast.TypeCast(typ, expr, expr.loc)
    elif self.context.equal_types('int', expr.typ) and \
            self.context.equal_types('byte', typ):
        expr = ast.TypeCast(typ, expr, expr.loc)
    elif self.context.equal_types('int', expr.typ) and \
            self.context.equal_types('float', typ):
        expr = ast.TypeCast(typ, expr, expr.loc)
    elif self.context.equal_types('int', expr.typ) and \
            self.context.equal_types('double', typ):
        expr = ast.TypeCast(typ, expr, expr.loc)
    elif self.context.equal_types('double', expr.typ) and \
            self.context.equal_types('float', typ):
        expr = ast.TypeCast(typ, expr, expr.loc)
    elif self.context.equal_types('float', expr.typ) and \
            self.context.equal_types('double', typ):
        expr = ast.TypeCast(typ, expr, expr.loc)
    elif self.context.equal_types('byte', expr.typ) and \
            self.context.equal_types('int', typ):
        expr = ast.TypeCast(typ, expr, expr.loc)
    else:
        raise SemanticError(
            "Cannot use '{}' as '{}'".format(expr.typ, typ), expr.loc)
    self.check_expr(expr)
    return expr
```

What this code does is check the 'source' type and the 'destination' type, and if these are of certain types, then do an automatic cast, otherwise, raise an error. The code works, but I want to add more variations of types, and I forsee this if-else tree will grow very large.

I've googled for a good solution and tried to read the sourcecode of clang, gcc and the C# compiler, but I could not find the sourcecode that takes care of this problem.

Are there any ideas on how to solve this problem, or pointers to sources where this is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

Simple! Just index types from narrowest to widest. For example:

```
byte = 0;
int = 1;
float = 2;
double = 3;
```

Then all you have to do is to compare the two:

```
if (from <= to)
{
    // This is a legal cast, no loss of precision
}
else
{
    // Error, narrowing!
}
```

I highly suggest [this](https://pragprog.com/book/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns) book.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the tip!